# What redistributable is required from end-users to run OpenCL applications?

Tags: opencl, nvidia, ati

I have developed a C++ application on a NVidia-based OpenCL architecture and wish to distribute it to end users.

Unfortunately, it appears that users with an ATI card cannot run my game as the dll that contains my OpenCL code won't even load (dynamically), while user with NVidia drivers appear to be able to load my dll.

What is the recommended 'best practice' when shipping an OpenCL-based app that 'runs anywhere'?  Is it possible for the app provider to insert all the dlls that will enable all users to use the app, or are users from different OpenCL architecture forced to download that architecture's OpenCL SDK?

Many thanks!

EDIT: Curiously the missing dll dependency was resolved by adding NVCuda.dll to my build. (Would like to remove that!)  However the answers provided here are quite useful for 'best practice' in regards to building an OpenCL app that can run on most platforms...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They need GPU drivers. For Intel CPU, they may manually download the necessary binaries.

AMD device compiler's compiling action takes some time while Nvidia's can compile quickly. Compiling time is very low when you target CPU. I converted a basic C++ fluid&raytracer simulation into opencl version and it compiled after 3 minutes!(I mean device opencl-c compiling of kernels) If you want to give people an already-compiled project, then you would need to have every single type of card on your access and compile&save binaries for all of them.

Some gl-cl-dx sharing operations can be incompatible between vendors.

Dont use platform-specific constants, they may not be mapped fully on other platforms.

Tell people your targeted opencl version.

Dont use larger than 256 local work group size for GPU computing. AMD GPUs' maximum local work group size is 256 while Nvidia's is 1024.

Dont spill private registers, decrease depth of pseudo-recursive functions if you need it badly. Sometimes AMD compiler tries to optimize so much that it explodes at native device compile time.

Use a "platform & device query wrapper" of your own that finds a proper gpu, dont just get platform[0] or device[0]. Users may have multiple platforms such as Intel's for CPU and AMD's for GPU, maybe all of them. APUs' included GPUs may be known as ACC instead of GPU(Im not sure about this)

Your implicit synchronization of kernels&buffer_transfers can successfully run on your system while not on other systems.

Check if your dlls or app is same bitness with other peoples' machine&OS. If you target 64 bit and they have 32bit OS then it will not work.

Comment: Thank you very much huseyin for that valuable info.  It looks like my usage of 1024 which was so nice on my NVdia build has to be reduced to 256 as you say and this will be a painful change!

So if I read you correctly than my users with either a decent NVidia or AMD card have everything they need to compile while users with just an Intel CPU require a download while finally users with just an AMD CPU have everything needed to compile?

Comment: It looks like my choice of parameters such as workgroup size = 1024 is going to haunt me... Has anyone seen a list of 'safe settings' that should run on most decent PC-gamer platform assuming a decent AMD or NVidia card less than 3 years old?

Answer (score 0):

The recent Catalyst Drivers from AMD should already provide OpenCL support. Of course, when someone has an old card without OpenCL support and/or not installed recent drivers, it might fall back to CPU-OpenCL or it might not work at all, repspectively. I'm not sure which assumptions you can make (regarding the system requirements that you state for your program), but at least there should be no need for own, dedicated "redistributables" when the target system has up-to-date drivers.

Comment: Thank you Marco13 for that useful post.  I will have to adjust to what the platform is more appropriately... just got bit because the 'prefix sum' algorithm I used can no longer work on AMD platforms and I have to find another alg to use!

Answer (score 0):

You should do this:

1. Use dynamic "OpenCL.dll/so" loading, this way your user do not need to have OpenCL at all. (Optional, but very helpful, you can even fall back to CPU mode. In addition, it will force you to use only pure OpenCL calls)
2. Use only common OpenCL methods, do never use company tuned methods that depend on additional DLLs. nVIDIA for example has a lot of tools inside OpenCL library that forces you to use it with nVIDIA libraries and drivers. These are for example calls that start with `oclXXX()`.
3. Write the kernels and the code in a generic way, do not expect everyone to have the same work-sizes, memory, etc.. You should be able to detect situations, and adapt your kernel to these facts. Use in place compiling of the kernels, and add `#defines` that control your behavior inside the kernel. Then you can define them from the outside by setting the hardware detected features. (only if you don't really care about your code security.

Answering your questions:

- You need to redistribute if needed the DLL from the vendor that you use (ie: nVIDIA) the client has to have the proper OpenCL enabled, even if it is from another manufacturer it should work.
- The best practices are to use a clean (non-vendor related) OpenCL code, so you don't force the client to install any specific library. And you don't need to install it or distribute it with your app.

Comment: Thanks very much DarkZeros for the useful post.  About your point #2 about not using oclXXX() calls, looking through my code I see calls such as oclGetPlatformID(), oclLoadProgSource(),  oclPrintDevInfo(), oclLogBuildInfo()... are you saying that my app can't run on AMD cards because of these calls?